# Can we bind Call Back function with Class property in Angular

Tags: angular

With JQuery  we can call Back function like this

```
$('.className').change(function(){// Do Something})
```

In Angular we can call Function like this

```
<input type='radio' (change)="myfunction()"/>
```

can we callback a function in Angular 7 also as we did in Jquery

Comment: Use MutationObserver:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver Which will allow you to observe the attribute chagne

Comment: You can use plain old javascript to achieve the same as jQuery using querySelector.

Comment: In general, using the DOM in Angular is a bad idea. What precisely are you trying to achieve? This sound a lot like an XY problem.

Comment: Actually i dont want to write (change)="myFunction()" on each common radio button so i want to do it as like we did using class name and then set function as a callback

Comment: Again, what precisely are you trying to achieve? Why do you need a change listener on a radio button in the first place? Have you read the documenation about Angular forms? If not, read it.

Comment: @MukulKhatter, you can pass an argument to the function `(change)="myFunction(1)"` if you want know more data, or use [(ngModel)] to binding the value with a variable, or use a ReactiveForm..., check the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/user-input and https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: So, @MukulKhatter you want to select all the input elements, for example, and bind a handler to a certain event of them? If so, use ViewChildren